# Aplicar sombra a contorno de objetos SVG con CSS

Tags: css, css3, svg

Quiero aplicar sombra al contorno de una imagen vectorial escalable, también conocidos como SVG.

El atributo **box-shadow** de CSS no es una opción ya que aplica sombra al "borde cuadrado imaginario" de la imagen (primera imagen) y lo que realmente se requiere es la sombra de la figura misma (segunda imagen, hecha con gimp).

Tengo entendido que así como existe el **fill** para colorizar la imagen, debiera existir también algún tipo de efecto que permita aplicar la sombra al borde.

La imagen usada es el SVG de material icons ubicable [aquí](https://material.io/resources/icons/?search=folder&icon=folder&style=baseline).

Gracias de antemano.

[image: Aplicando box-shadow]

[image: Lo que realmente se busca]

Answer (score 4):

#### 1. filter:drop-shadow()

utilizar `filter:drop-shadow` para aplicar la sombra a una imagen con transparencias

```css
.svgimg{filter:drop-shadow(1px 1px 3px #888)}
```

```html
<img class="svgimg" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/cat.svg#redcat" />
```

#### 2. filter:url()

Si quieres utilizar filtros svg puedes crear el filtro (`#f`) como el del siguiente ejemplo y utilizar `filter:url(#f);` para aplicarlo a tu imagen. El `filter:url()`permite aplicar todo tipo de filtros creados en SVG como por ejemplo el ya celebre *goo* (cosas pegajosas)

```css
.svgfilterimg{ filter:url(#f);}
```

```html
<img class="svgfilterimg" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/cat.svg#redcat" />

<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <filter id="f" >
       <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3" result="desenfoque"></feGaussianBlur>
       <feFlood flood-color="#888" />
       <feComposite in2="desenfoque" operator="in" />
       <feOffset dx="3" dy="3"></feOffset>
       <feMerge>
          <feMergeNode />
          <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
      </feMerge>  
    </filter>
  </defs>
 
</svg>
```

#### 3. Elementos SVG

Si en lugar de una imagen quieres utilizar *inline SVG*, o sea pequeños elementos svg utilizados dentro del documento HTML puedes aplicar el filtro como atributo del elemento svg "filtrado": `<rect ... filter="url(#f)"></rect>`

```html
<svg width="250" height="150">
<defs>
    <filter id="f" >
       <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3" result="desenfoque"></feGaussianBlur>
       <feFlood flood-color="#888" />
       <feComposite in2="desenfoque" operator="in" />
       <feOffset dx="3" dy="3"></feOffset>
       <feMerge>
          <feMergeNode />
          <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
      </feMerge>  
    </filter>
</defs>
<rect x="75" y="25" height="100" width="100" stroke="#000" fill="#f00" filter="url(#f)"></rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Agregas una clase al svg y aplicas la nueva propiedad 'filtro' de css.
Espero ser de ayuda.

```
.shadow {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( -5px -5px 5px #000 );//por ejemplo 
            filter: drop-shadow( -5px -5px 5px #000 );//por ejemplo 
}
```